# How to Resolve Delayed iron-ajax Response

Tags: ajax, iis, cors, polymer, timeout

I am trying to remove the bugs in this AJAX request.  When running this AJAX call it loads the template quickly, but after some time (I think the timeout), the following error is logged to the console.

> Failed to load https://api/endpoint:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Origin 'https://internal.msmni.com' is therefore not allowed access.

The application is hosted on IIS at `app.domain.com` and the API endpoint is at `api.domain.com`.

```
<iron-ajax id="ajaxCustomers"
  url="https://api/endpoint"
  method="post"
  handle-as="json"
  content-type="application/json"
  body="[[request]]"
  last-response="{{response}}"
  loading="{{loading}}"
  headers="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"></iron-ajax>
```

...

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[response]]" as="item">
  <p>[[customer]]</p>
</template>
```

Is there a way to properly set the header and/or configure the server to remove this error?

P.S.

I am using Node's Express and I have the following set in the `server.js` file.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, content-type, Accept, Authorization, x-api-key")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` means that your api doesn't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response as this needs to be returned by the server to allow breaking the Same-Origin Policy (it is not enogh to have it in the request) see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

So your api should set a header like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: app.domain.com` so your app is allowed to read the data.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the server settings.